# Set the HTTP Endpoint URL value for REST API from AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to have a serviceHost stage variable to be set for each request from API GATEWAY, exactly like picture attached below.

According to doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-set-stage-variables-aws-console.html we can have something like this from console, but since my app is totally on CDK so just wanted to figure out a way to have it configured through CDK itself.

Couldn't find that in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.IntegrationOptions.html or anywhere.

Is it possible to attain through CDK somehow.

[image]

Comment: You can look in the network tab of your browser devtools to see what API request the console sends when you change this value, from that you can figure out how to access it probably. Often things aren't yet fully documented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create stage variable input in API Gateway (REST API) using CDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70062565/create-stage-variable-input-in-api-gateway-rest-api-using-cdk)

Comment: Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the stage variables when declaring a stage. As per the [documentation](https://constructs.dev/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/v/1.133.0/api/awscdkawsapigatewaystage#awscdkawsapigatewaystagepropsparametervariables):

```py
import aws_cdk.aws_apigateway

my_stage = aws_cdk.aws_apigateway.Stage(
  self,
  "my_stage",
  variables = {"serviceHost": "my_value"}
)
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted @gshpychka, this defines the value as hardcoded which I dont want as per the usecase.

Comment: Stage variables are set for the stage, not per-request, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @sudiptdabral can you clarify?

Comment: You see that image I have pasted where serviceHost is a stage variable, I need to provide it a value each time I make a request through API Gateway Console. 
The doc I have attached in post tells us how to do it via console, I wanted to know is there a way to do similar thing via CDK because setting stage variable are not comming up as input.

Comment: That's impossible. Stage variables are set per stage, not per request. My answer shows how to do exactly the same thing as in the console.

Comment: Setting up the stage variable from CDK that come as a input in API gateway is what I am looking for

Comment: The answer shows how to achieve the same thing as you did in the console. The stage variable is set per stage and is not possible to change per-request.